# Inter processor Interrrupts in ARM cortex A9 ( How To write an handler for Software generated Interrupt ( ARM) in Linux? )

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, interrupt-handling

I read that the Software generated interrupts in ARM are used as Inter-processor interrupts. I can also see that 5 of those interrupts are already in use. I also know that ARM provides 16 Software generated interrupts.

In my application i am running a bare metal application on of the ARM-cortex cores and Linux on the other. I want to communicate some data from the core running bare metal application to the core which is running Linux. I plan to copy the data to the on chip memory ( which is shared) and I will trigger a SGI on the Core ( running linux) to indicate some data is available for it to process. Now I am able to generate the SGI from the core ( running bare-metal application ). But for handling the interrupt in the linux side, I am not sure of the SGI IRQ numbers which are free and I am also not sure whether i can use the IRQ number directly ( in general SGI are from 0-15). Does any one have an idea how to write a handler for SGI in Linux?

**Edit:**  This is a re-wording of the above text, because the question was closed for [SSCE reasons](http://sscce.org/).  The Cortex-A CPUs are used in multi-CPU systems.  An ARM *generic interrupt controller* (GIC) monitors all global interrupts and dispatches them to a particular CPU.  In order for individual CPUs to signal each other, a *software generated interrupt* (SGI) is sent from one core to the other; this uses *peripheral private interrupts* (PPI).  This question is,

> **How to implement a Linux kernel driver that can receive an SGI as a PPI?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does any one have an idea how to write a handler for SGI in Linux?

As you didn't give the Linux version, I will assume you work with the latest (or at least recent).  The ARM GIC has [device tree bindings](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/arm/gic.txt).  Typically, you need to specify the SGI interrupt number in a device tree node,

```
 ipc: ipc@address {
        compatible = "company,board-ipc"; /* Your driver */
        reg = <address range>;
        interrupts = <1 SGI 0x02>;  /* SGI is your CPU interrupt. */
        status = "enabled";
 };
```

The first number in the *interrupt* stanza denotes a *PPI*.  The *SGI* will probably be between 0-15 as this is where the SGI interrupts are routed (at least on a Cortex-A5).

Then you can just use the `platform_get_irq()` in your driver to get the *PPI* (peripheral private interrupt).  I guess that *address* is the shared memory (physical) where you wish to do the communications; maybe `reg` is not appropriate, but I think it will work.  This area will be remapped by the Linux MMU and you can use it with,

```
res = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
mem = devm_ioremap_resource(dev, res);
```

The *address* in the device tree above is a hex value of the physical address.  The `platform_get_irq()` should return an *irq number* which you can use with the `request_irq()` family of functions.  Just connect this to your routine.

**Edit:** Unfortunately, interrupts below 16 are forbidden by the Linux [irq-gic.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/irqchip/irq-gic.c).  For example, [`gic_handle_irq()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/irqchip/irq-gic.c#n282), limits handler to interrupts between 16 and 1020.  If SMP is enabled, then `handle_IPI()` is called for the interrupts of interest. [`gic_raise_softirq()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/irqchip/irq-gic.c#n651) can be used to signal an interrupt.  To handle the **SGI** with the current Linux, [smp.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/smp.c) needs additional [`enum ipi_msg_type`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/smp.c#n63) values and code to handle these in [`handle_IPI()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/smp.c#n544).  It looks like newer kernels (3.14+ perhaps?) may add a `set_ipi_handler()` to *smp.c* to make such a modification unneeded.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have couple of questions.  how do i populate the structures pdev and dev?. I suppose i cannot fill that using the probe function, since it is no hardware interrupt. And the <reg> field in the device tree entry will be the starting address of my shared physical memory(reg) and number of bytes which are to be accessed (range) Am i correct?

Comment: Both `pdev` and `dev` are sent to the `probe()` function.  `static int probe(struct platform_device *pdev)...`, `static struct platform_driver driver = { .probe = probe };` and `module_platform_driver(driver);` and `dev = &pdev->dev`.

Comment: See [ARM Cortex interrupt sources and types](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0407e/CCHDBEBE.html).  Section 4.3.15 of the GIC document gives the  `ICDSGIR`.  The `NSATT` specifies *trustzone* secure or not.  You can choose any interrupt not used (0-15).

Comment: @artlessnoise thank you. I solved this problem. I got an error ( EINVaL = -22 invalid arguement)  when i tried using the irq number in request_irq function( for all the SgI irq numbers ) so i used another funtion set_ipi_handlers (arch/arm/kernel/smp.c  ) to register my irq handler. I suppose request_irq cannot be used in this context.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that an example of such inter-core communication can be found in TI multicore SoC's (i.e. OMAP3530). Some time ago when I was using such a mechanism, means were provided by TI. Specifically, it was the DSPLink Linux device driver which was providing such a functionality. At that time, unfortunately, it wasn't an open source solution, but maybe there is some technical paper from TI describing how it works ... Just a direction what you could investigate further :)

EDIT: In the meantime, it seems that they've made it open source. So, if that's what you are looking for, you can have a look: [DSPLink](http://downloads.ti.com/dsps/dsps_public_sw/sdo_sb/targetcontent/DSPLink/index.html) and [SysLink (successor of DSPLink)](http://downloads.ti.com/dsps/dsps_public_sw/sdo_sb/targetcontent/syslink/index.html)

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look. :)