# Send Inter-Processor Interrupts in Zynq (arm-v7 / cortex-a9)

Tags: arm, interrupt, cpu-registers, armv7, cortex-a

I am trying to add multiprocessor support for an embedded operating system (DNA-OS) on the Zynq platform in the ZedBoard.
The OS is actually flawlessly functional with CPU_0 **alone**. The OS architecture requires the implementation of a *cpu_send_ipi* function in order to activate multiprocessing support: Basically, this function would interrupt a processor and give him a new thread to process.

I looked for an IPI register in the [ug585](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf) (Technical Reference Manual for Zynq) but couldn't find any.

I tried digging further in the Cortex-A9 spec for an IPI register, and found out that software generated interrupts could be used as IPI.

### After adding software interrupt support to my OS, the problem is that CPU_0 can interrupt itself, but cannot interrupt CPU_1 !

PS: for my OS to handle SGIs, I used the register spec from the ug585 in page 1486:
[image: SGI Control register]

So is there any other special configuration to permit CPUs to interrupt each others? or any other way to implement IPI ?

Regards,

Comment: See questions like [ARM bring up other CPU cores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055754/arm-start-wakeup-bringup-the-other-cpu-cores-aps-and-pass-execution-start-addre).  It is not clear if you have the 2nd CPU functioning?  I assumed you do in my answer.

Comment: [How to write a Linux SGI handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430733/inter-processor-interrrupts-in-arm-cortex-a9-how-to-write-an-handler-for-softw) has some pointers to different Linux source, which you can examine.

Comment: I did not put in place any code to start either of the CPUs. I actually compile the OS, along with the application to get a ~0.5MB elf file; I the use bootgen to generate a bin file from FSBL, my ELF file and my bitstream(s). I suppose FSBL loads my bitstream into FPGA, my elf into memory then points the PC of the CPU_0 to my OS entry point. 
Now after reading your comments and your answer, some code portions that I didn't understand earlier make sense. I will try to tweak the FSBL code to load the OS on both CPUs

Comment: There is a controle test in the OS kickstart module that enable CPU_0 to continue loading the OS kernel while blocking any other CPU waiting for interrupts.
Thanks for the hint, I will keep you updated once I make these changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reference documentation is a form of the GIC (global interrupt controller).  The Cortex-A9 MP cores include an integrated GIC controller.  Each CPU includes an **Interrupt interface**.  As well, there is a system wide **distributor**.  In order to receive the IPI (also known as SGI or *software generate interrupt*), you need to enable the CPU interface to receive the SGI interrupts on the 2nd CPU.  This entails several steps,

1. Configuring the GIC *interrupt interface registers* on CPU2.
2. Setting the CP15 vector table for CPU2.
3. Enabling the CPSR I-bit on CPU2
4. Possibly setting up some banked PPI distributor registers. <sup>note1</sup>

Note1: While most distributor registers are system global, some are banked per CPU as well.  For instance, see section 3.3.8. PPI Status Register in the Cortex-A9 MPcore TRM.  I don't see any from a cursory investigation, but I would not rule it out.

Testing that an unused SPI (shared peripheral interrupt) works by handling the vector on CPU2 by setting the GIC distributor *GICD_ISPEND* register on the CPU1.   This should verify that you have steps 2 and 3 covered.  You may also need to set the *type* to ensure that they are *interrupts* and not *FIQ*; especially if you have security support.  You need to use the *GICD_ITARGETSR* register to include CPU2.

### GIC reference list

- [ARM Generic GIC document](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ihi0048b/index.html) - registration needed, GICv1 (ignore GICv2 info).
- [ARM Cortex-A9 MPcore TRM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0407i/index.html) - chapter 3, for specific info.
- [PL390 TRM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0416b/DDI0416B_gic_pl390_r0p0_trm.pdf) - it is not spelled out anywhere, but I think this is the *integrated GIC*.  It maybe worth looking at if you use more esoteric features.

Especially useful in the **Appendix B** of the Generic GIC manual.  For some reason, ARM likes to keep changing the register names in each and every document they publish.

Comment: I do not have experience with Zynq CPUs.  It is possible that the Zync GIC does not *conform* to the ARM documents, but I would guess that is unlikely; they would have to do a custom design of the Cortex-A9 MPCore.